Can functional diodes and capacitors be printed on a PCB instead of soldering?
I want to print a fractal, capacitor circuit, network using diodes in strings of 3, with 2 capacitors in each circuit. The goal is to get 96 capacitors and 144+ diodes on the board. That is a lot of solder joints, and as the fractal develops, the element sizes diminish in scale. I'm hoping the network will serve to convert harvested, atmospheric, high voltage/low current power to higher current/lower voltage power.  Is this PCB feasible or would it be too costly for an experiment?

A is the basic circuit: 3 diodes + 2 capacitors
B is a fractal formation: 21 diodes + 8 capacitors


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I'll keep trying , and thanks for your answers so far.

What do you mean by "printed"?

480 solder joints is not so much. There are FPGA's that have over 1000 joints for a single IC.

Capacitors, yes. Diodes, no.

Capacitors, yes, but only very low values, only useful at 100s of MHz and above.

I fixed the first image. (You need to crop it before upload. It's about 80% white space.)


I want to print a fractal, capacitor circuit, network using diodes in strings of 3, with 2 capacitors in each circuit.

Ignoring the issue of whether the circuit will actually do what you think, this requires no special techniques.
Surface mount diodes and capacitors cost pennies each in high quantities. You'll have two part types - one capacitor, one diode. Just upload the design to JLCPcb or PCBway and they'll send back a fully populated board back to you. They can easily place thousands of those parts on a board if you'd want to. You'll also be paying for parts in high quantity so they'll be cheaper that way.

That is a lot of solder joints

When you get those boards manufactured, the machine will take a maybe 10 seconds to place that many components. The soldering is done with solder paste and reflow techniques. You'd be well advised to use them even if you were manually assembling the circuit. It's improves quality and is much faster. The paste should be printed using a stencil of course, not blobbed manually from a syringe :)

I'm not sure where you got the idea for the circuit, but I have my doubts that it will do anything useful at all. Or if it will not be completely useless, it'll be at least doing the job in a very inefficient way. You'd at least want to explore using high performance RF Schottky diodes as they have very low forward voltage and are meant for RF demodulation and switching.

You can't print diodes.
You can get some special PCB processes that can print resistors on pcbs.
But semiconductors require special processes in doping which would require diffusion processes in a vacuum chamber, and I am not aware of any manufacturers that do this.
But you can use very small diodes like 0201 components and that should suffice for your design.
If you really have to use small diodes you'd have to use a special process that you develop yourself.

You can print capacitors too, using special high Dk inner layer materials.

@ThePhoton But not semiconductors.
